# Activity node get executed in a template that accepts only Class type

Tags: acceleo

I have an uml diagram made with Topcased 5.2. The uml contains Class diagram and Activity Diagram. 
I wrote a template that accepts as parameter Class type in order to generate java classes.

The java classes were generated but in addition my method get executed for Activity node. How can I prevent execution of Activity node?

Following my template:

```
[template public generateEntity(c : Class)]
[comment @main /]
[file (c.getEntityFullPathFile().trim(), false)]
[c.generateEntity()/]
[/file]
[/template]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the UML metamodel (File > import > select "plugins and fragments", click 'next' then search for 'org.eclipse.uml2.uml', select it and 'Finish' the wizard). In there, you will see that an *Activity* is a *Class* (*Activity* inherits from *Behavior* which inherits from *Class*). That's all Acceleo 'sees'.

If you wish to generate your code for all Classes save for Activities, you can use a guard :

```
[template public generateEntity(c : Class) ? (not c.oclIsKindOf(Activity))]
...
```